# What's these number mean of kernel name?

Tags: linux, kernel

My kernel image name is like this:

```
3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
```

The '3.10.0' is kernel version number, what's '514.16.1' mean? Thank you~

Comment: https://unixy.net/secure/knowledgebase/104/What-does-el5-el6-and-el7-mean.html

Answer (score 0):

"514.16.1" is a distribution-specific maintenance release number. The distribution maintainers will include their own bug fixes, patches, extensions, etc., to the base kernel. If the distribution vendor fixes bugs or adds features, those changes may eventually find their way into the base kernel. However, customers usually want the fixes straight away -- or, at least, more quickly than the base kernel is updated. Consequently, distribution vendors need their own way of numbering kernels (and, indeed, everything else). Your example looks like a Red Hat version number, but I don't believe that Red Hat documents in detail how its kernel updates are numbered.